# In Swift fileExistsAtPath(_ path: String, isDirectory isDirectory: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool accepts single parameter only

Tags: ios, swift

The method fileExistsAtPath() in the example below accept single argument only.

```
if fm.fileExistsAtPath(result, isDirectory:&isDir) {
```

The exact error message is: "Extra argument 'isDirectory' in call".

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696044/nsfilemanager-fileexistsatpathisdirectory-and-swift

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some might find this a little neater. This is Swift 3.

```
var directory: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(false)
var exists: Bool = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: "…", isDirectory: &directory)

if exists && directory.boolValue {
    // Exists. Directory.
} else if exists {
    // Exists.
}
```

Comment: Technically this is not casting, but initialising with `init<T : BooleanType>(_ value: T)`.

Comment: When thinking about it you're completely correct, will remark this.

Answer (score 63):

The problem is that `isDirectory` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>` and not `UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>` you provide. You can use the following code:

```
var isDir = ObjCBool(false)
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath("", isDirectory: &isDir) {

}

if isDir.boolValue {

}
```

Comment: On Swift 3 Bool(isDir) is not working for me. isDir.boolValue works fine. Thanks

Comment: This is the solution for Swift 3

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
func isDirectory(path: String) -> Bool {
  var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
  NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
  return Bool(isDirectory)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3

```
var isDirectory:ObjCBool = true
var exists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: cachePath, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOveflow. Please add some explanation to your answer, as code-only answers are not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as an extension . to check if a directory exists or not in Swift 4.0

```
import Foundation

extension FileManager {

    func directoryExists (atPath path: String) -> Bool {
        var directoryExists = ObjCBool.init(false)
        let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory: &directoryExists)

        return fileExists && directoryExists.boolValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Swift 5.3.

```swift
var directoryExists: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(false)
        let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>(mutating: withUnsafePointer(to: &directoryExists){ $0 }))
```

It seems like not allowed to check file and directory in the same time.