# How do I check the value of a variable declared in swift of type UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?

Tags: swift

I need to check the value of a variable returned from a function in Swift with a type of UnsafeMutablePointer?.

Here's the declaration:

```
    var isDirectory: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?
```

When I print it out:

```
    print(isDirectory)
```

I get:

> nil

I am not very well versed in mixing Swift with Objective-C. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my actual entire code:

```
    let directoryURL: URL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

    let pathOldLocalStorage: String = directoryURL.path + "/OldLocalStorage"

    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: pathOldLocalStorage, contents: nil, attributes: nil)

    var isDirectory: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?

    let fileExists: Bool = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathOldLocalStorage, isDirectory: isDirectory)

    print("fileExists=", fileExists, "isDirectory=", isDirectory as Any)
```

Here is the debug window results:

> fileExists= true isDirectory= nil

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this:

```
var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false

let fileExists: Bool = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathOldLocalStorage, isDirectory: &isDirectory)

if fileExists {
    print("isDirectory=\(isDirectory)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum, you can find a little more in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26338640/6541007).