# Create directory in app group container swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I go about creating a directory in my App's group container?

I've tried using as the file manager:

```
let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER")!
```

but that doesn't create a directory...How can I go about creating a directory in this folder?

Comment: Look at `NSFileManager` > `createDirectoryAtURL..`

Comment: So I tried using NSFileManager but it still does not create a directory in my app groups shared container....Are you allowed to write to the container?

Comment: With NSFileManager how can I reference the shared app's container then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier` returns the URL to the group container.
To create a directory append the new directory name as path component

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if let directory = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER") {
    let newDirectory = directory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyDirectory")
    try? fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(newDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
}
```

Swift 3:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if let directory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER") {
    let newDirectory = directory.appendingPathComponent("MyDirectory")
    try? fileManager.createDirectory(at: newDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
}
```

Comment: This one should be now: `let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let directory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER") {
            let newDirectory = directory.appendingPathComponent("my_dir")
            try! fileManager.createDirectory(at: newDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        }`

A question: before creating a directory, isn't required to test if it exists a directory with the same name?

Comment: @IanBell It's good programming habit to test if an directory exists. You could set `withIntermediateDirectories` to true or use `try?` or `try` with a `do - catch` block.

Comment: hi @vadian i want to create folder in shared document directory and how to access folder data from share document directory.

Comment: What does *shared document directory* mean?

Comment: i am using custom keyboard extension then download keyboard theme from server and save in to document directory but app document directory can not access in custom keyboard extension so, required to share app group directory. how can i do please help me.

Comment: @ikbal Please ask a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547930/how-can-i-crate-and-access-share-app-group-document-directory

Answer (score 9):

1. Check you enable **"App Group"** entitlement. It can be enable from **project -> Capabilities -> App Group -> switch on**.[image]
2. Add an app group identifier **"group.com.companyName.exampleApp"** as above image.
3. Now you can access app group container using the specified identifier.

   ```
   let appIdentifier = "group.com.companyName.exampleApp"
   let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
   let container = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(appIdentifier)
   ```
4. If you set everything properly, you will get an URL address in "container".
5. Now,

   ```
   do{
      if let container = container {

       let directoryPath  = container.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sampleDirectory")

       var isDir : ObjCBool = false
       if let path = directoryPath?.path where fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory:&isDir) {
         if isDir {
           // file exists and is a directory
         } else {
           // file exists and is not a directory
         }
       } else if let directoryPath = directoryPath {
         // file or directory does not exist
         try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(directoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
       }
     }
   } catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.description)
   }
   ```

courtesy: file & directory checking code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24696209/2666902