# Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByAppendingPathComponent'

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3

I just converted my project to Swift 3 and I got an error to `directory.path` row:

> Error: Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByAppendingPathComponent'.

I've already tried `let realmPath = (directory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent` instead, I have got the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to type 'NSString' in coercion.

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    let directory: URL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.RazvanJulian.app")!
    let realmPath = directory.path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm") /* ERROR */

    RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath(realmPath)
    realmToken = RLMRealm.default().addNotificationBlock { note, realm in
        self.reloadTableData()
    }
    reloadTableData()
}
```

Please check it and let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541747/create-directory-in-app-group-container-swift

Comment: You are forcing to `NSString` which has `stringByAppendingPathComponent ` hence don't cast it

Answer (score 0):

`stringByAppendingPathComponent` became `appendingPathComponent` in Swift 3. Try this:

```
directory.appendingPathComponent("component")
```