# how to assign an ios swift project to a specific App Group

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I configure my iOS Swift project to be part of my App Group?
Can't find where to set this in Xcode.

I have created my App Group Identifier within: developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/ ..

I want all the files generated by the app to be accessible by my other apps, that will all be assigned to same App Group.

(This is development only; not for public distribution.)

Comment: see: [Create directory in app group container swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541747/create-directory-in-app-group-container-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View your target in Xcode (usually by clicking on the top level element in the project navigator)

Go to "Signing and Capabilities"

Click the "+ Capability" button.

Choose "App Groups"

Add the appropriate identifiers.