# Check if path is a directory in Swift2?

Tags: swift, directory, swift2, nsfilemanager

If like to attain functionality similar to that of Bash's `-d` `if` condition.

I am aware of how to test if a file exists with `fileExistsAtPath()`, which returns a bool "true" if the file exists and "false" if it doesn't (assuming `path` is a string containing the path to the file):

```
if NSFileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
    print("File exists")
} else {
    print("File does not exist")
}
```

However, I would like to check if the path specified in `path` is a directory, similar to the following `bash` code:

```
if [ -d "$path" ]; then
    echo "$path is a directory"
elif [ -f "$path" ]; then
    # this is effectively the same as fileExistsAtPath()
    echo "$path is a file"
fi
```

Is this possible, and if yes, how should it be performed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24696209/1187415

Comment: I agree, apologies. I've flagged this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use an overload of `fileExistsAtPath` that tells you that `path` represents a directory:

```
var isDir : ObjCBool = false
let path = ...
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory:&isDir) {
    print(isDir.boolValue ? "Directory exists" : "File exists")
} else {
    print("File does not exist")
}
```

Comment: how on earth is the solution we have to use in Swift. There really isnt a swift method?

Comment: @R.P.Carson I updated the answer for the new version of Swift.

Comment: Here we are 4 years later :D