# Creating a new subfolder in user's documents folder creates a file instead

Tags: ios, swift, directory, subdirectory, nsfilemanager

I have an issue creating a subfolder in the user's documents folder on an iPhone device and simulator. Have tried both on iOS 12 and iOS 13. Have tried different subfolder names.

```
let directoryURLs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let documentsFolderUrl = directoryURLs.first ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())

let pathUrl = documentsFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent("offline")
// have also tried with .appendingPathComponent("offline", isDirectory: true)

if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathUrl.absoluteURL.path) == false {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: pathUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        // have also tried .createDirectory(atPath: pathURL.absoluteURL.path)
    } catch(_) {
        print("OfflineManager: Cannot create download contents folder at path: \(pathUrl.absoluteURL.path)")
    }
}
```

The result of this operation is:

```
-rw-------  1 username  access_bpf    31K Apr 23 10:30 offline
```

and so this a file and thus I cannot create a subfolder and write files into it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Perhaps a *file* “offline” exists already from previous versions of your code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24696044/1187415 for some options to check for the existence of a file *and* whether it is a file or directory.

Comment: Have tried different subfolder names to no avail.